# Access denied to java executable on target file while building project with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have a multi-module project on IntelliJ Idea (version `2021.1.3`).

If I try to compile my module using command line (e.g. `mvn clean install`), the compilation goes fine.

However, if I try to Build the project via IntelliJ (which is a preliminary action to debug a unit test, with the IDE configured the same way than the command line - meaning same JDK, same Maven home, same Maven settings and local repository), then I get the following error coming from the O.S. (I guess that because the message I receive is in French, which is the language of my O.S.):

[image]

(Sorry I'm obscuring paths for privacy reasons, but I guarantee you is not relevant).

And the console error is:

```
java: D:\<path>\target\classes\<path>\rest-services.json (Accès refusé)
```

Where "accès refusé" is French for `Access denied`.

---

**Note:** unfortunately I cannot really include any debugging issue neither to provide a way to make the issue reproducible on someone else's side. The only purpose of this question is to find (if it exists) THE answer from someone who went across the same issue and found a way to solve it, so that when in the future someone looks for the same keyword - me included if I have this same problem in one year and will have by then forgot what I did to workaround it - will find a specific answer that can spare them 3 hours walking in the darkness.

---

So, this file gets copied from `src/main/resources` folder inside `target` over the build, but then the build itself tries to access it and apparently IntelliJ gets access refused by that.

The attempts I did based on similar threads I found around:

- I updated my IntelliJ Idea to the latest release
- I removed the file manually from the folder and relaunched the build (the file gets copied again and then access denied again)
- I completely cleaned and re-build by project with Maven before trying again
- I have run IntelliJ Idea with admin rights
- I have `File / Invalidate Caches / Invalidate Caches and Restart` multiple times on IntelliJ
- I have restarted my laptop
- I have checked with Windows Process Explorer and the file is not locked by anyone
- I have deleted and rebuilt the test configurations of IntelliJ

None of the above worked.

Finally, I ended up being able to make it work by checking-out the guilty file in the source code into my VCS, so that the read-only flag was cleared and the O.S. ended up giving IntelliJ the right to read it.

But this is not a "solution", just a workaround, and it may happen the same with a file on which I have no ability to do so (for example a self-generated file) - plus it's strange, there are many files with read-only flag being copied from source to target (including into the same folder where I had this issue), but yet this was the only file which was causing the problem.

Does anyone ever crossed such issue and if so, how did you solve it?

Comment: Do you have antivirus/firewall? Please try with it disabled or make sure that IDE [settings directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) IDE installation home, IDE executable and project files are excluded from the scan.

Comment: Also - do you build the code only by IDE? Do you use any code generation including launching 
3rd tools while IDE builds the code?